# Laravel How to properly handle values by id in an Eloquent Model

Tags: php, oop, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a Contact model like this

```
class Contact extends Eloquent
   {
   protected $table = "contacts";

   protected $position = array("frontend developer",
                               "light switch manager",
                               "product designer",
                               "head of tea kitchen");
   }
```

In my contacts table I want to store the contact's position using the $position array index as position-id, e.g.:

```
id     name               pos_id   email
--------------------------------------------------
1      George Teapotter   3        gtpot@maile.com
```

Now how would I effectively resolve the corresponding array string for the pos_id when querying the Contact model? I would need something like this in my query:

```
Contact::Select(name, **position(pos_id)**, email)->get();
```

to get as result for returning as json:

```
{ "George Teapotter", "head of tea kitchen", "gtpot@maile.com" }
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Storing the values in your code will lead to a world of pain. Either store the text in your table, or create a separate table for positions and use a foreign key in your contacts table.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. I just thought it ain't worth creating a separate table for 3 static entries only.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily with PHP, you don't need to do with mysql, your returned result is $rows so you can do this when you loop your result like this:

```
@foreach($rows as $row) 
<tr>
<td>{{$row->name}}</td>
<td>{{$position[$row->pos_id]}}</td>
<td>{{$row->email}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

if you want json encoded you can loop your result to do:

```
<?php 
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row->pos_id = $position[$row->pos_id];
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure, thanks Gouda. However I need to get the query results json_encoded for feeding it into a js datatable.

Comment: Thanks Gouda! 2 remarks on this one:

1. This is an onkey ajax search function and as such quite performance-sensitive. I was curious if there is a solution without doing an extra loop.

2. How would I access the protected $position array in your example?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to create another table in your DB for your position, as it means that you can then utilise Eloquent relations as well... There's hardly any performance overhead if you eager load your relation.

Comment: Thank you Samuel, could you give me an example on how I would eager load the relation:?

Comment: Say you name your relation `Position`, then you would load your contacts like this: `Contact::with('position')->get()`. In your contact class you would create the relation as `public function position()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo("Position","position_id","id");
    }   `